# How to consume WCF POST with List<Object> as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, http-post

i have a class definition like this:

```
public class Newuser
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<UserDetail> u_details{ get; set; } 

    }


public class UserDetail
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string age { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string gender { get; set; } 

    }
```

And declare `[OperationContract]` like:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "/addUser"
         )]
        void addUser(Newuser usr);
```

Usually, i use this following code to consume WCF POST:

```
 BudgetTransactionRequest cb = new BudgetTransactionRequest
                {
                    category = "category",
                    amount = 2000.000
                };

                WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
                proxy.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CreateBudget));
                serialize.WriteObject(ms, cb);
                byte[] data = proxy.UploadData("http://localhost:1910/Service1.svc/adduser", "POST", ms.ToArray());
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CreateBudget));
```

But, when the object contains a list, hard for me to find the proper way to consume this service. How to pass multiple object parameter through list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameter on WCF side to get value.

```
var username = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["username"];
```

var password= WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["password"];

```
 **This you can use  to consume WCF POST:**

      HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
       string baseAddress = "http://localhost:1910/Service1.svc";
        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseAddress + "/adduser?Username=" + username+ "&Password=" + password);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding = UTF-8";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(your_json_data);
            }
            resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;               
        }
```

Comment: I want to pass List of object from client code, could you give me an example code ?